# uiAlertController not dismissing someTimes

Tags: swift, xcode, uialertcontroller, http-get

I have login button which is http get service I run a popUp alert for waiting when user taps on button and I dismiss it when I fetch data.

but some times sucks on loading alert.test it on iPhone 5s but working on simulator properly.what I'm doing wrong??

```
    @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {


        phone=phoneText.text!

       if (validation(phone: phone)){

            popUpLoading()


           guard let url=URL(string: address+"uSers/checkUser/\(phone)") else{return}


            print(url)
            var requst=URLRequest(url: url)

            requst.httpMethod="GET"


            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requst, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                if let response=response{
                    //print(response)
                }
                if let data=data{



                    do{


                        let json=try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableLeaves) as! [String:Any]

                        print("jsom : ",json)

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {

                            self.popalert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

                                let data=json?["data"] as! String

                                print("data : ",data)

}
}
```

popalert variable is declared global

this is pop up alert for waiting :

```
func popUpLoading(){


    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.popalert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "wait...", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();
        self.present(self.popalert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.popalert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have called the dismiss function which is,

( self.popalert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { )

inside the response call. So the alert view will be hidden only if you are getting a proper response from the URL.

**You should be hiding the alert view in both scenarios**
 - so use `else` condition for `if` statement and dismiss the alertView

Comment: If you are using an alert view controller it is better to provide UIAlertAction for UIAlertcontroller. If not using an alert view action you can use a normal view. May I know the reason you are going for the alert view controller

Comment: thanks for replaying . I need to show waiting alert until I get the response from server.thats all

Comment: can I have a working model or screenshot of your query?

Comment: I have no access to server(java) codes. all I need to do is call a http get service and show a single code on a label which a got from get service.and until user waits for a service I should show a waiting alert